# How to represent crosstab data in java memory to provide category movements?

Tags: java, algorithm, plot, statistics, crosstab

I have a problem with both the loading and performing operations with crosstab(contingency table). 
I would like to load the data from a flat txt file (from crosstab) and store this in memory to print it as a mosiac plot later. The biggest problem I'm having, is how to store this in memory to make a possible category(lines of tab) switching. 
**The crosstab might be 3 or even 4 dimensional.**

Answer (score 0):

If the dimensionality is not fixed and you aren't terribly concerned with efficiency, I would suggest simply storing all of your crosstab cells in a single list. You can then create selections based on the dimensional coordinates using the following pattern:

```
class Cell{
    List<Integer> coordinates ...
    double value ...
}

class Selection{
    int dimension ...
    int start ...
    int end ...
    public boolean contains(Cell cell){
        int coord = cell.coordinates.get(dimension);
        return coord < end && coord >= start;
    }
}

class Crosstab{
    List<Cell> cells ... 
    public [double/int/object] tabulate(Selection selection)...
}
```